# UITableViewCell not refreshing

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, uitableview

In my uitableviewcell,i have tried to update the cell value by edit option, the value changes.if I'm not edit cell value it display the previous cell value.But actually the cell value from webservice is default one(0 or 1).If I'm not update it returns 0 from webservice.The code below do this ,

```
    if(![[[dict valueForKeyPath:@"KEYVALUE"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        cell.dropSetOrSuperSetLbl.text = @"value";
    }
    if(![[[dict valueForKeyPath:@"KEYVALUE"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"]){
        cell.dropSetOrSuperSetLbl.text = @"value";
    }
    if([[[dict valueForKeyPath:@"KEYVALUE"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"]&& [[[dict valueForKeyPath:@"KEYVALUE"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        cell.dropSetOrSuperSetLbl.text = @"value";
    }
```

I don't want to display anything if service returns '0' Please anybody help me fix it out.

Comment: check your tableview connection. Outlet is properly connected?

Answer (score 1):

Try like that:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.tableview reloadData]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your data is ready ( loaded ) call `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[self.tableview reloadData]` once your data gets loaded.